# JAX-RS Automatic unmarshalling of custom objects when receiving JSON in RESTEasy

Tags: java, json, java-8, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have two classes - Table and ExcelService.

There is one Values field in the Table (List >) and a lot of methods (the default constructor is also empty).

In ExcelService there is an ExportToCsv POST method which accepts an object of type Table as input (table). According to [this](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.17.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#JAXB_Collections) documentation and the [example](http://www.benchresources.net/resteasy-jax-rs-web-service-using-jaxb-json-example/), if application/json is set for @Consumes, then RESTEasy should automatically demarshall json into the Table table.

But no matter what I try to do, the table is always null. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong

I tried different versions of the packages and added XML attributes to the Table as in the documentation, there is no result. You should also add that the marshalling in the opposite direction (when RESTEasy sends json) works!

I'm testing a method under debugging with Postman:
[image]

My configuration and code:

Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>SimpleExcel.Api</artifactId>
    <groupId>simpleexcel.api</groupId>
    <name>SimpleExcel.Api</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/jaxrs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency><dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!--<build>-->
        <!--&lt;!&ndash; &ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--<finalName>ROOT</finalName>-->
    <!--</build>-->
    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Table.java:

```
package simpleexcel.api.models;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

/**
 * Table model
 */
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Table {

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return new Gson().toJson(Values);
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "values")
    private List<List<String>> Values;

    /**
     * 
     *
     */
    public Table()
    {
    }
    //...
}
```

ExcelService.java:

```
package simpleexcel.api.restServices;

import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.InputPart;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput;
import simpleexcel.api.models.Table;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Path("/table")
public class ExcelService
{
    @POST
    @Path("/export")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response ExportToCsv(Table table)
    {
        //**ERROR HERE** table always NULL 
        InputStream temp = table.ExportToCsv(";");

        return Response.ok().encoding("utf-8").entity(temp).build();
    }
    //...
}
```

I need the table to come filled (including Values field-list)

P.S I also looked at different articles here, maybe someone considers it a duplicate. Maybe so, but I have never met an example with the List < List < String > >

[Gitlab:](https://gitlab.com/Xambey/simpleexcel/tree/ApiServices/simpleexcel.api)

Answer (score 0):

I replaced MediaType with a string "application/json" in the Post method and it all worked... NotLikeThis

```
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("multipart/form-data")
```